# Does a signing provider has my private key (digital signatures)

Tags: digital-signature

For my essay im writing about digital signatures. Lets talk about an advanced digital signature which works with PKI (private-public key infrastructure). For example, im using ValidSign or GlobalSign service to digitally sign my document, do they have my private key to sign the document, or is it on my own machine? Im trying to understand why I should upload my document to a signing provider, why cant I just sign it on my machine and send it to the receiver?

Comment: You don't seem to understand the basics behind signatures or PKI in general.I reccomend you do some basic research.

Comment: I think u dont understand my question, why should one use a signing provider to sign a document?